# Git local: "failed to stat ... Permission denied"

Tags: git, gitlab

I got this error in pull or push in a Git local repository:

```
Cloning into 'porject.get'...
warning: failed to stat 'C:/.get/objects/02/20365a0796c99f07237a3fb8ba023b2caa8b79': Permission denied
fatal: failed to iterate over 'C:/.get//objects/'
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have a team/group of developers, and some developers can pull and push. Some developers can't pull and push. What is the problem with this?

Comment: Are you sure that the directory it mentions is called `C:/.get//objects`? And that it's "porject.get" instead of "project.git"? All in all my guess would be a typo at some point.

Comment: no this true niy,
but problem n't path project this example of for problem the but problem  true   push or pull files for many user

Answer (score 0):

In my case (in a Linux machine), upgrading git version solved this issue.